# Upload/download zip file

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to upload/download a ZIP file (containing multiple CSV/XLSX files) using R Shiny?

It is possible to do this with individual CSV/XLSX files, however the intention is to upload multiple files at once with the option to store the file without reading it into a dataframe.

Comment: Is there a problem with `fileInput`?